# Data Modeling in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, data-modeling

We are working on a website which contains native literature. whole website is designed as writer centric. Each writer has 8000 - 10000 articles/poems/books.

Client requires mongoDB to be used as a backend for this application. As a newbie, am confused in data modelling in mongo.

My question is, what is best approach? embedded data model or normalised data model for my use case.

```
Writer:{
       _id: ObjectID
    WriterName: String
    Email: String
    Article :[
       _id: ObjectID
       ArticleName: String
       CreatedDate: Date
       comments: [
           body: String
       ]
    ]
```

Or

```
Writer: {
    _id: ObjectID
    WriterName: String
    Email: String
}

Articles: {
    _id: ObjectID
    Writer_id: ObjectID
    ArticleName: String
    CreatedDate: Date
    comments: [
        body: String
    ]
}
```

We have another use case where we need to retrieve top 20 articles from all the writers articles. keeping in this mind what is the best solution? Also please let me know what will be the impact of document, if its size exceeds 16MB.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store this kind of data would be to create 2 collections and have reference both ways. Keep a list of articles in each writer's document and writerId in each article. 
like this:

```
Writers: { _id: ObjectID,
           WriterName: String,
           Email: String,
           Article :[ObjectID1, ObjectID2, ObjectID3]
         }

Articles: { _id: ObjectID,
            Writer_id: ObjectID,
            ArticleName: String,
            CreatedDate: Date,
            Comments: [ body: String ]
          }
```